# Machine learning options to detect errors in a large number of sql tables?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, anomaly-detection

I'm new to ML and want to build a system that can detect errors or anomalies in input data that I receive from customers. The data is structured in sql tables with various column names. The value types for each column varies but the most common are numbers, strings and dates.

Some of the values in these tables will be wrong. Examples of errors that I can encounter are:

- Null values or empty strings
- Truncated strings and/or numbers
- String formatted numbers
- Weird date formats
- Bad or missing references between tables

Up until now, the best option I can envision is to run some unsupervised edge case detection algorithm. But, from what I have understood by reading online about these algorithms, they do not really do much of machine learning. Rather just classify based on edge criterias.

The input data can reside in hundreds of tables with tens or hundreds of columns each. This means that just going through the data structure manually is a daunting task. My aim is a system that, just by looking at the data in one column, can detect data type and also automatically tell the outliers.

As I do think that there are patterns to be found in the errors that may occur and the fact that my dataset is huge, I would like to try out some semi-supervised algorithm where I could review the suggested errors from the algorithm classifying false positives etc. To feed back those assertions into the algorithm would improve the predictions I think.

Right now, I have started off using Python but have no clue on which algorithms to use and how to build a proper pipeline that adapts my input data to work well with the classifiers.

I would be very grateful if someone can give me suggestions on which algorithms and steps I could use to implement the system I have in mind or suggest already existing tools for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Currently, I am not quite sure what the actual problem is. If most of the input are numbers, strings and dates, I would assume simple "check if date is valid", "check if number in certain interval" or "string contains xy" would help you a lot already. There is not always a need of ML (saying this as a huge supporter of ML). If the combination of all values entered results in "anomalies", you can use anomaly detection to find outliers. But for that, I think you have to be a bit more precise with your question!

Comment: You might consider using *"Benford's Law"* a.k.a. *first-digit law*  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law if applicable.

Comment: This is not a machine learning problem. You don't to train anything to remove the unwanted values. You just need to write a program to detect them. Regex for the date format, regex for number format, check if not null, etc.

Comment: Hi! Thank you all three for your comments. Now that you confront me with it, I think you may be correct that I should not try to tackle the problem with ML. As I am not entirely sure how to describe the issue in a better way but I have updated the message a bit. I hope this brings more clarity on what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Null values or empty strings: an ML algorithm will probably not accept such an input
- Truncated strings in numbers: ?
- String formatted numbers: numbers are always formatted as strings
- Weird date formats: an ML system will require huge samples before it learns rules that you can implement in two minutes
- Bad or missing references between tables: how could an ML algorithm deal with this ???

IMO, you forget the most important check: values out of the normal range. These ranges can be found by simple statistical observation or by... *common sense*.